# glom assign based on data

Tags: python, assign, glom

In the following code, I am trying to mask personal information  based on data. I have two scenarioes.  In scenario 1, I want to update when type = 'FirstName', update or assign valueString value to "Masked". In scenario 2, I want to update when type matches the pattern  "first****Name", update or assign valueString value to "Masked". I was wondering if anyone have suggestions for writing glom assign statements to solve the above cases.

Example Json String

```
{
"id": "985babac-9999-8888-8887",
"entity": [
{
"what": {
"reference": "4lincoln-123-11eb-bc1a-732f"
},
"detail": [
{
"type": "uuid",
"valueString": "4obama-f199-77eb-bc1a-555555704d2f"
},
{
"type": "firstName",
"valueString": "John"
},
{
"type": "userName",
"valueString": "Johns"
},
{
"type": "middleInitial",
"valueString": "S"
},
{
"type": "lastName",
"valueString": "Trump"
},
{
"type": "first-4fa999-f1999-Name",
"valueString": "John"
},
{
"type": "birth-4fa999-f1999-Date",
"valueString": "2010-01-01"
}
]
}
]
}
```

Updated output should look like the following

```
{
"id": "985babac-9999-8888-8887",
"entity": [
{
"what": {
"reference": "4lincoln-123-11eb-bc1a-732f"
},
"detail": [
{
"type": "uuid",
"valueString": "4obama-f199-77eb-bc1a-555555704d2f"
},
{
"type": "firstName",
"valueString": "Masked"
},
{
"type": "userName",
"valueString": "Johns"
},
{
"type": "middleInitial",
"valueString": "S"
},
{
"type": "lastName",
"valueString": "Trump"
},
{
"type": "first-4fa999-f1999-Name",
"valueString": "Masked"
},
{
"type": "birth-4fa999-f1999-Date",
"valueString": "2010-01-01"
}
]
}
]
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, code-wise? What output did what you tried actually produce?

Comment: TBH, I don’t know about glom; but might be an easy job for regex.

Comment: I was able to update straight forward scenario, that when key is given, updating the value.  For example,  I define keys in a list , I will loop through the list and update each key.  path_list = [ id, entity.o.what.reference ] ; for spec_key in path_list:  _ = assign(data, spec_key, "Mased") .  I could not figure out to define spec for data driven  keys and values.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution. I was wondering if this can be done in one glom call instead of calling multiple times?

```
import json
import logging
import sys
import time
import re
from glom import glom, assign, Coalesce, SKIP, Spec, Path, Call, T, Iter, Inspect

LOGGING_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - [%(filename)s:%(name)s:%(lineno)d] - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
LOGLEVEL = logging.INFO

logging.basicConfig(level=LOGLEVEL,format=LOGGING_FORMAT)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


start_time = time.time()

target = {
"id": "985babac-9999-8888-8887",
"entity": [
{
"what": {
"reference": "4lincoln-123-11eb-bc1a-732f"
},
"detail": [
{
"type": "uuid",
"valueString": "4obama-f199-77eb-bc1a-555555704d2f"
},
{
"type": "firstName",
"valueString": "John"
},
{
"type": "userName",
"valueString": "Johns"
},
{
"type": "middleInitial",
"valueString": "S"
},
{
"type": "lastName",
"valueString": "Trump"
},
{
"type": "first-4fa999-f1999-Name",
"valueString": "John"
},
{
"type": "birth-4fa999-f1999-Date",
"valueString": "2010-01-01"
}
]
}
]
}

# def myupdate(x):
#     for count, item in enumerate(x):
#         myspec = 'entity.0.detail.{}.valueString'.format(count)
#         if item == 'firstName':
#             _ = assign(target,myspec,'Masked')

piiRegex = re.compile(r'^first.*Name$|^last.*Name$|^middle.*Initial$|^birth.*Date$')


def myupdate(x):
    for count, item in enumerate(x):
        myspec = 'entity.0.detail.{}.valueString'.format(count)
        mo = piiRegex.search(item)
        if mo:
            _ = assign(target,myspec,'Masked')
        

spec = {'result': ('entity.0.detail', ['type'], myupdate)}

xyz = glom(target, spec)
print(xyz)
print(target)




logger.info("Program completed in --- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

===============

Result:

```
{'result': None}
{'id': '985babac-9999-8888-8887', 'entity': [{'what': {'reference': '4lincoln-123-11eb-bc1a-732f'}, 'detail': [{'type': 'uuid', 'valueString': '4obama-f199-77eb-bc1a-555555704d2f'}, {'type': 'firstName', 'valueString': 'Masked'}, {'type': 'userName', 'valueString': 'Johns'}, {'type': 'middleInitial', 'valueString': 'Masked'}, {'type': 'lastName', 'valueString': 'Masked'}, {'type': 'first-4fa999-f1999-Name', 'valueString': 'Masked'}, {'type': 'birth-4fa999-f1999-Date', 'valueString': 'Masked'}]}]}
```